# Mapping Increments valused to an array in Java with lambdas

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming

I'm trying to fill an array with incrementing values using a lambda expression.
Ex. [1, 2, 3, 4, ... n]

```
        List<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<Integer>(i);
        nums.stream().map(n -> IntStream.rangeClosed(1, i));
```

This is what I came up with. i is an arbitrary value passed into the method. How can I get this to function like I want? Alternately how do I do something similar?

Comment: Why do you need `nums`? `IntStream` can generate a range of integers for you?

Comment: probably `IntStream.range(1, i+1).forEach(nums::add);`

Comment: If your question was "how to build a list of incremental integers from 1 to n using Java Stream API", this should do the trick: `return IntStream.range(1, n + 1).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a list not an array.  So this should do it.

```
List<Integer> nums = IntStream.rangeClosed(1,n).boxed().toList();
// or for an array
int[] nums = IntStream.rangeClosed(1,n).toArray();
```

This will also work using the Arrays class.

```
int[] nums = new int[n];
Arrays.setAll(nums,i->i+1);
```